# Number of bits after stop bit before going to idle state. Is it regulated by a industrial standard?

Tags: uart, rs485, bus

Does anyone know a number of bits after stop bit before going to idle state.
Is there any standard on this matter (e.g. industrial)?

***Update:***

[image]
So my questions are: What marked areas stand for. What are scientific or engineering names?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94941/discussion-on-question-by-deputyofcopypaster-number-of-bits-after-stop-bit-befor).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

the green section:

Atmel calls it "guard time" where the tx_enable output stays high after the stop bit. (so the transmitter stay active transmitting the UART idle signal)

Such  a practice may be useful to combat dielectic absopbtion in the signal wire so that the line doesn't change state as soon as the transmitter releases it.

The purple section is when the line is idle and the only signal is the small voltage from what looks to be fail-safe termination.

Comment: Dave Tweed is a good influence on you.))

Speaking seriously. Is the green section length regulated by a rule or whatever?
Concerning the violet one. Can it be  just shutdown mode of the driver?

Comment: I'm not aware of any rule,  but there are many different uses for RS485, and there may be such a rule in your use-case.

Comment: Just found, FYI, Siemens specified for its devices. After stop bit, it goes 3,5 bits length, then the drive goes to shutdown mode. It's looks like a true. if judging on the picture. My device isn't Siemens, though. However, it meets their rules. Probably it's a common rule.

Comment: So my next question is: I don't clearly see. What watches those 3,5 bits in order to put driver in shutdown mode. Which way it happens, generally?

Comment: the UART (or the CPU) commmands the driver to turn off the trasmitter some time after the UART transmit shift register and buffer empty.